# How to call custom aosp service from android app

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-source, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am working on a project which runs on aosp. I added a system service to aosp. I run this service with using adb shell "service call" command successfully. While creating service, I applied following ways.

1. Added an aidl file
2. Added a .java file which derived from aidl
3. Added jni file.

After creating service, I wrote an basic android app. I want to call this service from this android app. How I can call this service from android app.

Comment: If you want to be able to obtain it from your app using `getSystemService` suppose you'd have to modify `SystemServiceRegistry.java`, `Context.java` (and possibly some other files) in frameworks/base.

Answer (score 4):

Create a service manager in: `frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/MySerManager.java` next to the .aidl interface definition.

In `frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Context.java`
search for a simple service like VIBRATOR_SERVICE and add MYSER_SERIVCE to every occurrence.

In particular add: `public static final String MYSER_SERVICE = "myser";`

Do the same in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SystemServiceRegistry.java`
making sure to add:

```
import android.os.MySerManager;

registerService(Context.MYSER_SERVICE, MySerManager.class,
        new CachedServiceFetcher<MySerManager>() {
    @Override
    public MySerManager createService(ContextImpl ctx) {
        return new MySerManager();
    }});
```

This service manager can be used outside of the AOSP by building the sdk: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt

And within the AOSP by getting the system service from the Context:

```
MySerManager mySerManager = (MySerManager)getSystemService(Context.MYSER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve how system service calls from android app. After compiling aosp, classes.jar in framework_intermediates file is created to out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES. I added classes.jar to my android app and I used following codes.

```
IBinder binder = ServiceManager.getService("my_service");
IMyService myService = IMyService.Stub.asInterface(binder);
int result = myService.myFunction();
```